# Login in Codeigniter not working

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

I'm new in CodeIgniter, and have problem with Login function. It's always return "Wrong password or username" as my msg, but my table 'admin' with username = admin, password = admin. I have showed the array to see the return, and it returned admin, admin (the field that I inputted). I have load model, libraries and helper on autoload.php file, and I don't understand where is my error, and any suggestion to help me show username and pass stored on table 'admin' (to sure that I have connected database rightly)

This is my controller

```
public function index(){

    $data['title'] = SITE_NAME.': Login';
    $data['msg'] = '';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('admin/home_view', $data);
        return;
    }

    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $userRow = $this->Admin_model->authenticate_admin($this->input->post('username'), $password);
    if(!$userRow){
        $data['msg'] = 'Sai tên đăng nhập hoặc password';
        $this->load->view('admin/home_view', $data);
        return;
    }

    $admin_data = array(
            'admin_id' => $userRow->id,
             'name' => $userRow->admin_username,
             'is_admin_login' => TRUE);
    $this->session->set_userdata($admin_data);

    redirect(base_url().'admin/dashboard','');      
}
```

My View

```
<div class="loginfrm">
<img src="<?php echo base_url('public/images/admin_images/logo.png');?>" class="mainlogologin">
 <div class="err"><?php echo($msg);?> <?php print_r($test);?></div>
<form method="post" action="">
  <div class="formwrp">
    <label>Tên đăng nhập</label> 
    <input name="username" class="frmfield" id="username" type="text">
    <?php echo form_error('username', '<div class="err"><span>', '</span></div>'); ?>
    <label>Mật khẩu</label>
    <input name="password" class="frmfield" id="password" type="password">
    <?php echo form_error('password', '<div class="err"><span>', '</span></div>'); ?>
    <div class="logbtnwr">
      <input value="Đăng nhập" class="loginbtn" type="submit">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And my model

```
    <?php
class Admin_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
       // parent::__construct();
       $this->load->database();
    }

public function update($data){
    $return=$this->db->update('pp_admin', $data);
    return $return;
}



public function authenticate_admin($user_name, $password) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('pp_admin');
    $this->db->where('admin_username', $user_name);
    $this->db->where('admin_password', $password);
    $Q = $this->db->get();
    if ($Q->num_rows > 0) {
        $return = $Q->row();
    } else {
        $return = 0;
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $return;
}
```

Thanks in advance. I have searched many sites but don't know where my error. Sorry if this topic is identical

Comment: remove xss_clean from the validation rules , no longer exists in validation rules

Comment: where you define authenticate_admin  show it

Comment: calling the wrong method to check username and password,replace $this->admin_model->authenticate_admin to $this->admin_model->kiemtra_admin

Comment: thanks, in my code, they're same name 'authenticate_admin', but I copy wrongly, sorry for this stupid mistake, but they're same name and still error

Comment: 1. Your code suggests that your admin field name for username is username, but later you refer to it as admin_username. Do you have both? 2. Your index method in your controller never defines $username, so not sure how you are seeing a value for that.

Comment: ^ solid point! @HuệVũ did you try this?

Comment: actually, I have copied wrong method, the method exactlly is 'authenticate_admin', and the field username is admin_username.
$username has deleted, so there is no error about this part. Last, I have login successfully. thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Can you do us and yourself a favor? Edit the question to reflect things properly. Whatever you copied wrong please fix. The edit button is just under the question by your name. The issue is here if the actual field name is `admin_username` then `$this->db->where('username', $user_name);` should  be `$this->db->where('admin_username', $user_name);`

Comment: yeah, this is the first time I ask question in stackoverflow, so please excuse me, I have fixed the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function index() {

    $data['title'] = SITE_NAME . ': Login';
    $data['msg'] = '';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('admin/home_view', $data);
        return;
    }

    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $userRow = $this->admin_model->authenticate_admin($this->input->post('username'), $password);
    if (!$userRow) {
        var_dump($userRow);
        $data['msg'] = 'Sai tên đăng nhập hoặc password';
        $data['test'] = array($username, $password); //this is array to show the input
        $this->load->view('admin/home_view', $data);
        return;
    }

    echo 'it worked! <pre>';
    print_r($userRow);
    exit;

    $admin_data = array(
        'admin_id' => $userRow->id,
        'name' => $userRow->admin_username,
        'is_admin_login' => TRUE);
    $this->session->set_userdata($admin_data);

    redirect(base_url() . 'admin/dashboard', '');
}
```

Model:

```
public function authenticate_admin($user_name, $password) {
    $this->db->where('username', $user_name);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);
    $query = $this->db->get('admin');
    if ($query->num_rows == 1) {
        return $query->row();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And see what it is outputting. If it continues to output false and enter the conditional statement then you know one of the following things (1) you are incorrectly entering the username and/or password (2) you are entering the "correct" username and password you just have the details incorrectly stored in the db.

Also:

1. Hash your passwords **never store plaintext passwords in db**
2. Use an existing system like Ion Auth

Comment: It returns bool(false), and I'm sure that I'm entering correctly the username and pass, and I don't encrypt pass in db, is there the problem? Maybe I should use Ion Auth as you said

Comment: Niether of those additional suggestions will affect your current code it was just for future. If I were you I'd truncate the table and try and enter the details again and see if that works. There is no logical explanation as to why it is returning false aside from the details being incorrect.